# Erro ao adicionar strings em um array

Tags: java, android, array

Minha *activity* de uma aplicação Android tem esse código.

```
public class gerenciar2 extends ActionBarActivity{
    boolean editar=false, adcionar=false, remover=false;
    SQLiteDatabase Banco = null;
    Cursor cursor;
    String tabbanco="Tabela1";
    TextView gerenciar;
    ListView lista;
    String tabelas[];
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gerenciamento);
        lista = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.list);
        abrebanco();
        buscardados();
        gerelista();


        }



    public void gerelista() {
        cursor.moveToLast();
        int x=cursor.getCount();
        int y=1;
        while(y<x){
        //nextdado();   
        tabelas[x]=retornadado();   
        dadoanterior();
        y++;
        };
        //return tabelas;

    }


    public boolean dadoanterior() {
        try{
            cursor.moveToPrevious();
            return true;

        }
        catch(Exception erro){
            return false;

        }

    }

    public boolean buscardados(){
        try{
            cursor = Banco.query("tabela",
                    new String [] {"tabelas",}
            , null, null, null, null, null);

            if (cursor.getCount() != 0){
                cursor.moveToFirst();

            }else{
                String sql = "INSERT INTO tabela (tabelas) " +
                          "values (Tabela1) ";
                    Banco.execSQL(sql);
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception erro){
            Exibirmensagem("BANCO", "erro ao buscar no banco: "+ erro.getMessage(), "ok");
            return false;
        }
    }
    public String retornadado(){
        String dado = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tabelas"));
        return dado;
    }
    public void abrebanco(){
        try{
            Banco = openOrCreateDatabase("banco", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);
            String sql ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabela (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" +
                    ", tabelas TEXT)";
            Banco.execSQL(sql);

        }
        catch(Exception erro){
            Exibirmensagem("BANCO", "erro ao criar banco: =/"+ erro.getMessage(), "ok");
        }
    }
```

O erro "no Intent" é nesta linha:

```
tabelas[x]=retornadado();
```

Se eu comento essa linha a activity roda.

Estou tratando o *array* de forma errada?

Comment: Qual o erro, Você pode ver no Logcat?

Comment: Qual erro retorna? Não faço ideia do que seja erro de Intent. A variável `tabelas` tem algum elemento? Não está parecendo. Será que perdi alguma coisa? Se não tiver nenhum elemento vai dar erro de `index` ou algo assim.

Comment: então acusa erro no intent de chamar a activity. 
ele n fala mais nada. 
não, nao tem nenhum elemento, eu queria adcionar

Comment: Por que você não usa ORM Lite ?  :D
http://www.dclick.com.br/2012/05/24/databases-em-android-ormlite-3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que você quer fazer isto (provavelmente o `y` precisa ser inicializado com 0, mas sei lá, você pode estar querendo fazer alguma outra coisa que eu não percebi):

```
public void geraLista() {
    cursor.moveToLast();
    int x = cursor.getCount();
    for(int y = 1; y < x; y++){
        //nextdado();   
        tabelas.Add(retornadado());   
        dadoanterior();
    };
    return tabelas;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/Filter.java).

Mas tem um detalhe extra, você não poderá usar um *array* (que tem tamanho fixo, não pode adicionar novos elementos), terá que usar uma `ArrayList`, a declaração deverá ser:

```
ArrayList<String> tabelas;
```

E obviamente precisará adaptar onde possa ser necessário. Até existe como continuar um *array* mas seria errado para a intenção deste código e nem vou falar sobre.

Precisando converter novamente para *array* pode fazer o seguinte:

```
String[] array = tabelas.toArray(new String[tabelas.size()]);
```

Isto está um pouco esquisito, normalmente tem outras formas, provavelmente mais confiáveis, de pegar todos os dados e adicionar neste *array*. Mas o problema que você está apontando deve ser resolvido assim.

Comment: nada.. da erro:
cannot invoke Add(String) on the array type String[]

Comment: Eu comi bola. Você editar e adicionar algo importante para o que você está querendo fazer.

Comment: eu tenho um array de strings vazio e quero adicionar conteúdo do banco de dados nele para exibir numa lista sem usar o listactivity

Comment: deu certo se inicializo. 
preciso agora converter o arraylist em array como faço isso?

Comment: Isso poderia ser outra pergunta mas vou quebrar seu galho :)